# How to align grouped boxplot across subplots in plotly

Tags: r, plotly, boxplot, r-plotly

I am trying to subplot my box plots using `plotly` so that boxes of the same color line up with each other on the x-axis. However, when I separate them using `boxmode = group`:

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  w = rep(1:3, times = 2, each = 60),
  x = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), times = 20),
  y = rep(c("D", "E", "F"), each = 20),
  z = rnorm(120)
)

p <- function(val) {
  filter(df, w == val) %>% 
    plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~z, color = ~y, type = "box") %>% 
    layout(boxmode = "group")
} 

subplot(lapply(unique(df$w), p), nrows = 3, shareX = TRUE)
```

This doesn't occur when using `ggplot`:

```
(ggp <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = z, color = y)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(. ~ w, nrow = 3))
```

But it does occur once again if I try pass this plot to `ggplotly()`:

```
ggplotly(ggp) %>% 
  layout(boxmode = "group")
```

Removing `boxmode = "group"` causes boxes of different colors to stack over each other, which is even worse! I've tried some alterations using `alignmentgroup` & `offsetgroup` but they appear to override the `boxmode` argument and cause everything to stack again. Is there anything else I can do to generate an interactive plot that keeps each box in their lane?

There are similar issues [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/3402) but I don't think this solves my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Being used to `ggplot2` this feels quite awkward but it works. The trick is to add the boxplots for the single groups as separate traces and to set the `offsetgroup`. Try this:

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  w = rep(1:3, times = 2, each = 60),
  x = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), times = 20),
  y = rep(c("D", "E", "F"), each = 20),
  z = rnorm(120)
)

p <- function(val) {
  df <- filter(df, w == val)
  # 1. Step by step
  # plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~z, color = ~y) %>% 
  #   #purrr::reduce(unique(df$y), ~ add_trace(.y, data = filter(df, y == .x), type = "box", offsetgroup = .x))
  #   add_trace(data = filter(df, y == "D"), type = "box", offsetgroup = "D") %>%
  #   add_trace(data = filter(df, y == "E"), type = "box", offsetgroup = "E") %>%
  #   add_trace(data = filter(df, y == "F"), type = "box", offsetgroup = "F")

  # 2. using purrr::reduce
  purrr::reduce(unique(df$y), function(.x, .y) {
    add_trace(.x, data = filter(df, y == .y), type = "box", 
              offsetgroup = .y)
    }, .init = plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~z, color = ~y))
} 

subplot(lapply(unique(df$w), p), nrows = 3, shareX = TRUE) %>% 
  layout(boxmode = "group")
```

Gives me this plot:

[image]

Comment: I have a question. I used to use `layout(boxmode = "group")` as well. Today, I ran my old code and found that `layout()` is not taking `boxmode` any more. Your code and my code are still running with a warning. I wonder if you know any update about this update. If not, boxmode, what can we use?

Comment: Hi jazzurro. As far as I get it the warnings are just warnings. When I run the code I get a warning about a compatibility issue with dplyr. To the best of my knowledge this issue is fixed in the devel version of plotly and probably should be fixed with the next release. The second warning related to boxmode is also not problematic. To the best of my knowledge this is related to the fact that the plotly package is not up to date with plotly.js, i.e. the plotly package does not know about this option but plotly.js does. That's why the code works. Best S.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I will just wait for the next update. Cheers.